# How to find the answer of $\det[A^{-1}+4 \space adj(A)]$

Tags: matrices, determinant

How to solve the following questoin?

> If A is a $3 \times 3$ matrix and $\det(A)=2$, find $\det[A^{-1}+4 \space \rm adj(A)]$.

Can I do this?

> \begin{eqnarray}
> \\ \det[A^{-1}+4 \space \rm adj(A)] &=& \det(A^{-1})+4A^{-1}\det(A)\\
> \\&=& \dfrac{1}{\det\left(A\right)}+4A^{-1}\det\left(A\right)\\
> \\&=& \frac{1}{2}+8A^{-1}\\
> \end{eqnarray}

but it seems like a wrong answer. What is the right answer?

There is one more question : Can I rewrite $\det(A^{-1})$ as $\det(A)^{-1}$?

---

***Thank you for your attention***

Comment: You should start by noting that ${\rm adj} A=\det A\cdot A^{-1}$. And careful, $\det(A+B)\neq \det A+\det B$ in general.

Comment: My teacher haven't told me how to calculate $det(A+B)$...so I try it. Haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the answer from the solution paper.
[image]